# Setting the default value of a column on a parent table whose value is dependent on a column value of a child table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit new to SQL and having some trouble coming up with this query. I have two tables, a parent `x` table, and a child `y` table which references the parent table via a `x_id` foreign key:

`x` table:

| x_id | col_to_update |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

`y` table:

| x_id | testing_enum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |

I'd like to add the new column `col_to_update` and set its default value based on whether there exists a row in `y` with the same `x_id` and a value set for `testing_enum`. For example, for `x_id=1`, since there is a row in `y` for that `x_id` and a value set for `ftesting_enum`, I want to then default the `col_to_update` for that `x_id` to `1`. Hopefully that makes sense. I think this involves a JOIN clause but I'm unsure of how everything is supposed to come together.

Comment: Do you want to update once, or you want this column to be updated "on the fly"?

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention, ideally we could set this to be the default value of the column

Comment: sorry about that! I edited the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: If this is one-time task then common UPDATE will solve. If you want the value to be updated on-the-fly then you'd use triggers. *ideally we could set this to be the default value of the column* - impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One-time update:

```
UPDATE policies 
SET col_to_update = EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                             FROM policies_sub 
                             WHERE policies_sub.policy_id = policies.policy_id
                               AND policies_sub.factor_enum
                            )
```

On-the-fly actualization:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_factor_enum
AFTER INSERT ON factor_enum
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE policies 
SET col_to_update = EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                             FROM policies_sub 
                             WHERE policy_id = NEW.policy_id
                               AND factor_enum
                            )
WHERE policy_id = NEW.policy_id
```

and the same triggers AFTER DELETE (use OLD.policy_id) and AFTER UPDATE (use both - i.e. 2 UPDATEs).

After triggers creation run one-time UPDATE once for current values actualization.

Comment: this is super helpful and easy to follow, thank you!